# How to create a nested layout in PyQt6 and where do I add the widgets?

Tags: pyqt6, nestedlayout

I'm new to PyQt 6. For a small project I'm trying to achieve a nested layout as shown below:
[mockup testcases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6C57.png). So far I took the sample code from [15 Minute Apps](https://github.com/pythonguis/15-minute-apps/tree/master/browser) to get some kind of webbrowser. How and especially where I have to add the needed widgets?

My layout should look something like this:

- TabLayout

  - Tab Testcase

    - FormArea
    - WebView
  - Tab Results

    - TableView1
    - TableView2

What I have so far is following:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtPrintSupport import *

import os
import sys


class AboutDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        QBtn = QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Ok  # No cancel
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        title = QLabel("MooseAche")
        font = title.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        title.setFont(font)

        layout.addWidget(title)

        logo = QLabel()
        logo.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'ma-icon-128.png')))
        layout.addWidget(logo)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Version 23.35.211.233232"))
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Copyright 2015 MooseAche Inc."))

        for i in range(0, layout.count()):
            layout.itemAt(i).setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
              # TabLayout ....? 
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.heise.de"))

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        navtb.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.addToolBar(navtb)

        back_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'arrow-180.png')), "Back", self)
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)

        next_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'arrow-000.png')), "Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'arrow-circle-315.png')), "Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'home.png')), "Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        navtb.addSeparator()

        self.httpsicon = QLabel()  # Yes, really!
        self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'lock-nossl.png')))
        navtb.addWidget(self.httpsicon)

        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        stop_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'cross-circle.png')), "Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        # Uncomment to disable native menubar on Mac
        # self.menuBar().setNativeMenuBar(False)

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")

        open_file_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'disk--arrow.png')), "Open file...", self)
        open_file_action.setStatusTip("Open from file")
        open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        file_menu.addAction(open_file_action)

        save_file_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'disk--pencil.png')), "Save Page As...", self)
        save_file_action.setStatusTip("Save current page to file")
        save_file_action.triggered.connect(self.save_file)
        file_menu.addAction(save_file_action)

        print_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'printer.png')), "Print...", self)
        print_action.setStatusTip("Print current page")
        print_action.triggered.connect(self.print_page)
        file_menu.addAction(print_action)

        help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Help")

        about_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'question.png')), "About MooseAche", self)
        about_action.setStatusTip("Find out more about MooseAche")  # Hungry!
        about_action.triggered.connect(self.about)
        help_menu.addAction(about_action)

        navigate_mozarella_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'lifebuoy.png')), "MooseAche Homepage", self)
        navigate_mozarella_action.setStatusTip("Go to MooseAche Homepage")
        navigate_mozarella_action.triggered.connect(self.navigate_mozarella)
        help_menu.addAction(navigate_mozarella_action)
        self.show()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'ma-icon-64.png')))

    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("%s - MooseAche" % title)

    def navigate_mozarella(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.udemy.com/522076"))

    def about(self):
        dlg = AboutDialog()
        dlg.exec()

    def open_file(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "",
                                                  "Hypertext Markup Language (*.htm *.html);;"
                                                  "All files (*.*)")

        if filename:
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                html = f.read()

            self.browser.setHtml(html)
            self.urlbar.setText(filename)

    def save_file(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Page As", "",
                                                  "Hypertext Markup Language (*.htm *html);;"
                                                  "All files (*.*)")

        if filename:
            html = self.browser.page().toHtml()
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(html)

    def print_page(self):
        dlg = QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dlg.paintRequested.connect(self.browser.print)
        dlg.exec()

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

    def navigate_to_url(self):  # Does not receive the Url
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == "":
            q.setScheme("http")

        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    def update_urlbar(self, q):

        if q.scheme() == 'https':
            # Secure padlock icon
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'lock-ssl.png')))

        else:
            # Insecure padlock icon
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'lock-nossl.png')))

        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("MooseAche")
    app.setOrganizationName("MooseAche")
    app.setOrganizationDomain("MooseAche.org")
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I'd say: start by looking into `QTabwidget`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html and layout managers: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html